# Dont want to pass opacity to font in android

Tags: android, fonts, opacity

I have taken one card view .applied black color to its background and i have taken text view and applied background image and passed opacity to `textview` for getting blackish image in output.but i don't want to apply opacity to the font on image.please help.
Here is the code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#000000"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ICE CREAM WITH CRANBERRY SYRUP"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/recp_one"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're using the term opacity correctly.  Is the problem that you're not able to read the full text because of the color of the image behind it?  That's not an opacity issue.

Comment: THe other answers are right that you shouldn't be using a background for this (it should be a separate view for the image).  But to make the text standout you can use shadowColor="#FFFFFFFF" to add a shadow to the text, so it will stand out against whatever color is beneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying Image background for the `Textview` is not good in your case, Instead of that you can create `ImageView` and `Textview` different and apply what ever properties you need.

it should look something like below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#000000"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/recp_one"
            android:alpha="0.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ICE CREAM WITH CRANBERRY SYRUP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#000000"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/recp_one" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ICE CREAM WITH CRANBERRY SYRUP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My solution is using both of `ImageView` and `TextView`, to resolve your issue